# Renaming files in PHP?

Tags: php

I want the script to go into the folder 'images', take every file, cut the first four characters and rename it.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$path = './images/';

if ($handle = opendir($path))
{
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if($fileName!=".." && $fileName!=".")
        {
            $newName = substr($fileName, 4);
            $fileName = $path . $fileName;
            $newName = $path . $newName;

            rename($fileName, $newName);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

This is how the files in the images folder are named:

```
0,78test-1.jpg
0,32test-2.jpg
0,43test-3.jpg
0,99test-4.jpg
```

and this is what i want them to look like:

```
test-1.jpg
test-2.jpg
test-3.jpg
test-4.jpg
```

The problem is the script cuts out the first 8, 12 or 16 characters, not four as i want it! So when i execute it my files look like this:

```
-1.jpg
-2.jpg
-3.jpg
-4.jpg
```

**UPDATE**

I also tracked the packages to make sure i am not executing the script multiple times. The script is only executed once!

Comment: `$newName = substr( $fileName, 4, strlen( $fileName ) );` ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it is not working.

Comment: your code works for me:-https://eval.in/650573

Comment: `0,78` is not a part of name?

Comment: i used your code and is work for me perfectly. But we you hit the enter or page reload two times then you got -1,-2 types of file name.

Comment: Yes you are right, i changed it a little bit for the example, one sec.

Comment: Okay that is weird ... As soon as i only use that script on a couple files it works, but if i have many files like 30 or 40 it doesnt work anymore ...

Comment: I updated the filelist! With those files it does not work!

Comment: still your main code works in this case too:- https://eval.in/650584    . I am talking about this code `$newName = substr($fileName, 4);`

Comment: This is the weird thing! If i get the filenames with an ECHO like echo $newName it works! I see the correct name, but they still get not renamed correctly!

Comment: are there any errors in the php error log?

Comment: @RamRaider Hey. No, there are no errors. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post again, so you can see the output i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach though essentially the same with the `substr` part this worked fine for tests on local system.

```
$dir='c:/temp2/tmpimgs/';
$files=glob( $dir . '*.*' );
$files=preg_grep( '@(\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.png$)@i', $files );


foreach( $files as $filename ){
    try{

        $path=pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME );
        $name=pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
        $newname=$path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr( $name, 4, strlen( $name ) );

        if( strlen( $filename ) > 4 ) rename( $filename, $newname );

    } catch( Exception $e ){
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly fine, though im still confused why my approach did not work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this little Function. It would do just the proper renaming for you:

```
<?php

    $path   = './images/';

    function renameFilesInDir($dir){
        $files   = scandir($dir);

        // LOOP THROUGH THE FILES AND RENAME THEM
        // APPROPRIATELY...
        foreach($files as $key=>$file){
            $fileName   = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
            if(is_file($fileName) && !preg_match("#^\.#", $file)){
                $newFileName = preg_replace("#\d{1,},\d{1,}#", "", $fileName);
                rename($fileName, $newFileName);
            }
        }
    }

    renameFilesInDir($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = './images/';

if ($handle = opendir($path))
{
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if($fileName!=".." && $fileName!=".")
        {

//change below line and find first occurence of '-' and then replace everything before this with 'test' or any keyword
            $newName = substr($fileName, 4);

            $fileName = $path . $fileName;
            $newName = $path . $newName;

            rename($fileName, $newName);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```